# song lyric idiom

Tags: music

Well, I went upon the mountain - I looked down in the sea
I seen the crabs and the fishes - Doin' the be-bop-bee.

'Cause My Bucket's Got A Hole In It
Yea! My Bucket's Got A Hole In It
Yea! My Bucket's Got A Hole In It
I can't buy no beer.

Comment: Can you say exactly what your question is? is it about a particular word choice here? or Syntax? and of what exactly? (song lyrics are usually difficult to judge because with poetry anything goes).